# Move Watson Studio Visual Recognition Model to Desktop App

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-studio, visual-recognition, watson-studio-desktop

I had created a visual recognition model through Watson Studio last year for a school project and the day of the presentation there was some sort of issue with the server and I was unable to run the model. I see now that there is a Watson Studio Desktop app, but I am still trying to figure out my way around. **Is there a way to transfer my already pre-trained visual recognition model from the Watson Studio online to the desktop app?** The project is linked to a pi camera and a robotic arm and I would like to see if I can get it to work through the desktop app while I have the free trial

Comment: Is the desktop app more of a tool like Tableau? From what I see it's pretty similar to node red, which is what I had originally used in combination with the visual recognition model.

Answer (score 0):

"Offline" Visual Recognition is not supported by Watson Studio Desktop.  However, with the v4 API (Custom Object Detection) you can export your model from the API and run it locally (offline) on an Android device that supports RenderScript (most do).

For docs:
  https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/visual-recognition/visual-recognition-v4#get-a-model